# Update controller data into laravel after middleware

Tags: laravel, filter, controller, response, middleware

I have one `ProjectController` with function `getAll()`. In `getAll()` I use eloquent `ModelName::get()` to fetch all projects and assigned to one variable `$projectList`.

I register one after middleware. In that middleware, I want to do some data filter on `$projectList` which I get in the controller.

Please help me how can I do that?

Comment: Show code or no help. Controller (relevant stuff), middleware (whole file).

Comment: After research I found that I can not update $projectList varibale in after middleware which is  set in controller function. I have to use global scope to add where condition into query and I will get updated result directly in $projectList.